# Declaring additional properties on an inferred type

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a constructor that returns a complex object who's type is partly inferred. Now I want to add some properties to that returned type. I don't want to declare them on the class. Is there a way to do this?

```
type AdditionalProps = {
 myAdditionalProp : string
}

const myInstance: inferredType & AdditionalProps = new MyClass()
myInstance.myAdditionalProp = "I love typescript."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to add new props to newly created object.
The type is inferred correctly, but can be stated explicitly as well.

```ts
class MyClass {
  id: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = 1;
  }
}

type AdditionalProps = {
 myAdditionalProp : string
}

const myInstance: MyClass & AdditionalProps = Object.assign(new MyClass(), {myAdditionalProp: 'I love typescript.'});
// NOTE: the type can be inferred
console.log(myInstance.id);
console.log(myInstance.myAdditionalProp);
```

Comment: That's a great trick. I often find myself dealing with generics and inferred types and I'm left wondering how to extend them, when generic arguments need to be copied through and nested generics aren't supported. This looks great, I just add the properties on the right side of the assignment and there they are.